# C# and Wireless

Tags: c#, wireless

I need some books or tutorials or solutions how i can get little information about all computer which is connected in my wi-fi network. 
It will be good if in book or in tutorial will be clearly written everything about c# and wireless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/WifiScanner.aspx)